# discord.py-rewrite - How to overwrite and change cooldown for certain users?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Since my previous post was locked, I decided to be more concise about what I want this time. So I have a discord bot, written in Python (3), and I want to decorate all my commands with user-basis cooldowns, to prevent potential abuse. But, I want the bot developers to bypass completely this cooldown, and if possible, I would like that if the command invoker's is in a specific list of ids, overwrite his cooldown (so that he would only have to wait 3 seconds instead of 5 for example). I tried this:

```py
class Bot(commands.Bot):
    class Cooldown:
        def __init__(self, rate=1, per=3.0, ctype=commands.BucketType.user):
            self.rate = rate
            self.per = float(per)
            self.ctype = ctype
            self.cmd_cldwn = commands.cooldown(rate, per, ctype)
        def __call__(self):
            def pred(ctx):
                if ctx.author.id in bot_developers:
                    return True
                ctx = self.cmd_cldwn(ctx)
                return commands.Command.is_on_cooldown(self, ctx)
            return commands.check(pred)
```

But then I don't know how to use it. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the solution, by creating a `CooldownMapping` class.

Comment: Can you send a link to what you used or your code for this? Thanks